# Does removal of unit production from the grammar may increase number of total production?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

There are m variable in a grammar. The number of productions after removal of unit productions in the worst case is ,(Assume there are no null productions)

(a) O(m)
(b) O($m^2$)

(c) O($k^m$)

(d) O($2^m$)

---

My attempt:

He asked about number of total production remains in the minimized grammar ,
 so , if the there is no null production , it is advantage , as you know when we convert a grammar without null production , generally , removal of all production introduces new production in the resultant grammar (it can be upto set of all subset of given max RHS number of variable , so exponetial ) .

But , in given grammar , you don't have null production , so you are removing only unit production (i.e. A--->B type productions ) , resultant grammar maximum 'm' production , where m is number of variable . 
example :-
S---->A
A---->B
B---->a/b/c
resultant grammar ,
S---->a/b/c
So , it is O(m) time .

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: Hint: there is more than one correct answer. (What is $k$?)

Comment: $k$ is constant

Comment: Then *all* answers are correct (if $k\geq 2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the grammar
$$S \to \overbrace{X\cdots X}^{\text{$n$ times}} \\ X\to a|b$$
What happens when you remove unit productions?

Comment: Resultant grammar will be S--->a|b|..|a|b....2n-times , so total number of productions are O(2n) , _minimized grammar is S--->a|b_ . 
rt , sir ?

Comment: No, the minimized grammar is rather different from $S\to a|b$.

Comment: If I am consider given grammar as S---->XXXXX....n-times, and X---->a|b ,
then minimized grammar should be O($2^n$) productions . Sir, Again I have two queris (1) Is the production S----->XXXXX... unit production ? 
(2) If , there was X---->a|b|....m-times , then the minimized productions O($m^n$) ? 
Am I rt ?